# How to edit only 1 column from a datatable?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatable

I have a datagrid with a datatable as datasource. I have added a checkboxColumn but I can not edit it due to the datagrid is not allowed for edit.

My questionis, is there a way which the only editable column is the checkboxColumn? so the checkbox can be changed but not the rest of the columns.

Thank you.

Comment: Either change the datatable when adding it to the datasource or change the data in the datagrid itemdatabound event... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What UI do you use (WPF, WinForms)? What do you mean by "the datagrid is not allowed for edit"? Is it set to readonly or what? Please, show the code where you initialize your datagrid, set it to readonly and add checkBoxColumns.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about WinForms:

Change `ReadOnly` property of your DataGrid to `FALSE`.

Change `IsReadOnly` property of your CheckboxColumn to `FALSE`.

Change `IsReadOnly` property of your other columns to `TRUE`.